# env data output is right but not accepted

Tags: node.js, forms, email, environment-variables, nodemailer

When ever I use .env file I get this error:
Error: Invalid login: 535 Authentication failed { ...., code: 'EAUTH', response: '535 Authentication failed', responseCode: 535, command: 'AUTH PLAIN' }
the output is right but still doesn't work.
PS: put an ehtereal email only works for testing

**Edit:** After correcting the code the problem turned out to be in the SMTP server itself not the data

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('dotenv').config();
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

 async function main() {
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
      port: 587,
      secure: false,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.USER,
        pass: process.env.PASS,
      },
    });
let info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: , // sender address
      to: , // list of receivers
      subject: , // Subject line
      text: , // plain text body
      html: , // html body
    });

    console.log(process.env.USER, process.env.PASS);
    console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
    // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
```

.env file

```
USER=bernita24@ethereal.email
PASS=3xkrh13VBcSuy7MAdM
```

Comment: Try by changing `secure: false` with `secure: true`

Comment: it outputs this: [Error: 8728:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:332:
] {
  library: 'SSL routines',
  function: 'ssl3_get_record',
  reason: 'wrong version number',
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  command: 'CONN'
}

Comment: and i the documentation it says: true for 465, false for other ports